# Use a grepped file as an included source in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I'm on a shared webhost where I don't have permission to edit the global bash configuration file at `/ect/bashrc`. Unfortunately there is one line in the global file, `mesg y`, which puts the terminal in tty mode and makes `scp` and similar commands unavailable.  My local `~./bashrc` includes the global file as a source, like so:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

My current workaround uses `grep` to output the global file, sans offending line, into a local file and use *that* as a source.

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    grep -v mesg /etc/bashrc > ~/.bash_global
    . ~/.bash_global
fi
```

Is there a way to do include a grepped file like this without the intermediate step of creating an actual file? Something like this?

```
. grep -v mesg /etc/bashrc > ~/.bash_global
```

Comment: Why not just use `mesg n` in your ~/.bashrc?  In any case, you can specify the file to grep or redirect grep's stdin; don't use cat uselessly.

Comment: 'Grokked' is not the past tense of 'grep'. http://www.google.com/search?q=define:grok

Comment: Changed to grepped…

`mesg n` still seems to force the terminal into some type of tty session

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lose the cat, its useless

```
source <(grep -v "mesg" /etc/bashrc)
```

the `<()` syntax is called [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
. <(grep -v mesg /etc/bashrc)
```

Comment: That did it. I guess I was looking for the `<()` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to call  `mesg n` :)

Comment: Calling `mesg n` after `mesg y` has been called globally still seems to force it into tty mode. I'm still getting `stdin: is not a tty
` as an error…

Answer (score 1):

From memory, but something like

```
grep -v mesg /etc/bashrc | eval
```

should do the trick

Since i'm not sure eval will read stdin, you may need to rephrase it into

```
eval `grep -v mesg /etc/bashrc`
```

Comment: But then how can I use that as a source with the `.` command? `. eval `stuff`` doesn't work…

Comment: You don't need to source it.. eval will essentially do the same thing

Comment: have you tried ? Create a simple file, called "testprofile" and inside it, `export TEST="something"`. now, do the `grep` and `eval` on `testprofile` and see if $TEST has the value.