# TortoiseSVN + PuTTY, Win10, Network connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, putty

Summary: a clean install of current TortoiseSVN (1.14.1) can not use a clean install of current PuTTY (0.76) using default keys. Error is "Unable to connect to a repository at URL ... Network connection closed unexpectedly" but is unrelated to problem linked below that googling locates.

I am trying to set up TortoiseSVN on a new Windows 10 virtual machine. I have installed PuTTY-64 and set up Pageant. There's a PuTTY saved configuration named 'svn', and if I have started Pageant, then connecting to svn brings me to a bash prompt without requiring a password. So far, so good.

From TortoiseSVN, browsing the repository at svn+ssh://iain.brown@svn/s/svn/sw gives "Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://iain.brown@svn/s/svn/sw'. To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file. Network connection closed unexpectedly."

The URL is connect. (For certainty I copied and pasted from an older TortoiseSVN setup.) The PuTTY configuration appears to be correct, and in fact if I right-click on the explorer and change TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Network -> SSH client to PuTTY's own plink, browsing the repository works fine. I would leave it like that and call it done, except for the 20-odd windows that pop up. Since I want to replicate this environment for other developers I don't want to deal with the complaints this will cause.

So I *believe* that if plink.exe works it isn't a configuration problem, but it's also hard for me to believe that it's a TortoiseSVN bug (having tried the last couple of versions) unless there's a very recent incompatibility between PuTTY and TortoiseSVN that isn't yet showing up in Google searches.

Changing the SSH client to TortoisePlink.exe gives the exact same connection closed error as leaving it blank, so it does appear that the error is coming from TortoisePlink. Error is 'Unable to connect to a repository at URL ... Network connection closed unexpectedly' but is unrelated to the problem linked below found by googling this term.

There's a similar report here: [TortiseSVN svn+ssh Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ... Network connection closed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606950/tortisesvn-svnssh-error-unable-to-connect-to-a-repository-at-url-network-c) which refers to the TortoiseSVN FAQ in the solution, but my PuTTY registry values don't include a default name, and there seems to be no *mesg* in the shell profile chain. (The Subversion server is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day trying to learn when PuTTY and TortoiseSVN became incompatible, I finally figured out it isn't the program version but the format of the key file that has changed. If I save the PuTTY key file as V2, as in the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1647896/putty-key-format-too-new-when-using-ppk-file-for-putty-ssh-key-authentication TortoiseSVN works with PuTTY, including the 32- and 64-bit current version (PuTTY 0.76, TortoiseSVN 1.14.1).

So until TortoisePlink recognizes the V3 PuTTY keyfile, I think this is the answer.